# Invalid Credential with XOAuth2 for Gmail

Tags: google-oauth

Recently, I am trying to get e-mails from Gmail, using XOAuth2 protocol.
Especially, I am using "OAuth2Authenticator.java" from https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/downloads/list.

But, I always get an invalid credential error like the follwoing:

A1 NO [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure)
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:566)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:265)

Before reading, due to the limitation of putting a link, I cannot write "httoo://" so that please think of that this http header is front of some url information.

Before posting this question, I think I looked most of the articles about this one. Many articles are about using OAuth1.0 (deprecated) But, I still cannot figure out how I can make it work with OAuth2 & XOAuth2. I appreciate any suggestion/helps.

The following is the steps I am taking:

1. get an access token through OAuth2 with the scope of mail.google.com/
2. just put this access token & gmail account (e.g. test@gmail.com) into "OAuth2Authenticator.java".

After this procedure, I always get invalid credential.

The interesting stuff is that I can get unread mails through Feed URL (i.e. https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom) which is specified in Google OAuth2.0 Playground.

This indicates that I am sure that I get the correct access token. But, does not work at all for IMAP with this sample code.

Actually, the scope "mail.google.com/" is not included in the list of Google OAuth2.0 Playground.

For getting access token for XOAuth2, is there any other special way to get access token?

For the official page about XOAuth2, we need to use base64 to encode the access token.
But, I think the sample code is doing this procedure.

Also, SMTP of this sample did not work at all. But, after changing the properties, I could make it work. Is this code old?
But, unfortunately, what I need is IMAP. But, after trying setting some different/new properties, IMAP does not work at all....

I am stuck on this problem for a long time. So, I posted this question.
I really appreciate any suggestion/helps.

Regards

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol? Do you have a protocol trace? What are you using for your imap library?   Xoauth2 is very different than http bearer oauth.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Max. I read it. But, I think I did not completely understand how I can actually do "IMAP Protocal exchange". So, I am using the provided libraries&examples in the url you provided. Actually, I notice that there is a little difference between my code's output & "IMAP Protocol exchange". In my output, checking A0 capability. Then, check A1 capability. But, the official  "IMAP protocol exchange" is to check C0 capability. Then, check A1 capability. Do you think this is a reason?

Comment: Also, I found this web-site http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-gmail-imap-web-applications. But, this looks that we can use IMAP for only the restricted domain, i.e. not arbitrary users. Does this mean that we can access GMail through IMAP for only restricted domain?

Comment: Uh, you're missing a major part of the IMAP protocol.  The first part of any command is a 'tag', which is arbitrary, but allows you to match server responses with client commands.  You can use IMAP with any gmail account.  You need to take the access token you're given, concatenate it with the username, the \x01 characters, and then base64 that as part of the IMAP AUTHENTICATE command.

Comment: Thank again, Max. Sorry. What is a command? So, I send a command through Java, right? I understand I should look up. But, we concatenate base64 with username, accesstoken, and \x01 characters?? I thought base64 is a concatenated string of username, access token, and \x01 characters like user=someuser@example.com^Aauth=Bearer vF9dft4qmTc2Nvb3RlckBhdHRhdmlzdGEuY29tCg==^A^A.

Comment: So, maybe in this case, command is something like A1, A0?

Comment: Actually, in sample code, "OAuth2SaslClient.java" is dong "byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", email,
                                    oauthToken).getBytes();". Is this different from what you say??

Comment: I think I figured out what you say. Really thank you! Max!

Comment: Each IMAP request you due to the server is a command.  Each command is preceded by an arbitrary tag.  Usually in examples, they start at A0 and count up.  But any set of letters can be used, but they should change from command to command.   Good luck.  CAPABILITY is a command.  LOGIN is a command.  SELECT is a command.

Comment: I could create a program from your advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out your problem regarding invalid credentials

```
A1 NO [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure) Exception in thread "main"        
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure) at 
com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:566) at
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:265)
```

To remove above error you have to invalidate your Token and get a new token using below code

```
1- accountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", token);
```

after invalidate token you have to get Refresh token using below code

```
String newToken = AccountManager.get(this).getAuthToken(new Account(account,"com.google"),
             AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, null, null).getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

using new token now you are able to login.